# How to get multiple account balances in trc20 network

Tags: node.js, blockchain, smartcontracts, tron, tronweb

I'm developing a dapp with node.js and i have several wallets that I need to check their balances in a short amount of time. when I make a for loop in my wallet addresses and check them individually. I get `503 error` from tronweb(I have tried the API too and it had given me the same error) because I'm trying to get so many wallet addresses at the same time. Now I'm searching for a tool or package or anything that can query multiple wallet addresses balance. but I didn't find anything at all. Can anyone help me with that ???